# Run librxtxSerial.so on Embedded Linux Device

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, beagleboneblack

I am currently trying to interface a RFID reader unit.
The provided SDK offers a test project in Java.
On my windows system it does work.
The target device, however, is an embedded Linux device.
I tested it on a BeagleBone Black (32 Bit, Buster IoT Debian) and a Raspberry Pi 3 (64 Bit, Manjaro and RaspberryPiOS).
In both cases, I am able to install the JDK (JDK8_u131) but cannot start the test project.
In the picture below you can see the error message.
[error on raspberryPiOS, 64 Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jr8U.png)

Any tips?

Thx!

Comment: And how exactly did you install librxtx? I see a package "librxtx-java" which should contain the library, alternatively you can [compile it from source](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux)

Answer (score 0):

I found libRXTXSerial convenient for Windows in Java, but for Linux to avoid native code, why not just opening the device file directly using `FileInputStream` / `FileOutputStream`. Before doing that, you'd have to initialize with
`/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyS1 raw -echo 115200`